# Bind to Button in dynamic view

Tags: java, android, events, event-handling

I try to code in java/android the first time and I am a bit frustrated that my years of c# knowledge do not seem to help me very much.

Currently I try to create a buttonclick-event that should be bound to a button that is inside a view that is loaded dynamicly.

Part of my activity:

```
 private Button myButton;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 String selectedMenu=getArguments().getString(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
   if (selectedMenu==getString(R.string.title_test)) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
        myButton=rootView.findViewById("@+id/buttonTest"); // ERROR?
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }
  return  null;
}

 public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v==myButton) { 
       // magic stuff
    }
 }
```

And my button definition:

```
 <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test starten"
            android:id="@+id/buttonTest"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="TestSoap_OnClick" />
```

In the line "ERROR" I try to get the Button from the View. How can I access it?

And just for my understanding: As a button seems to be a view: Is "View" in Java about the same as "Control" in C# WinForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace 
`myButton = rootView.findViewById("@+id/buttonTest");` with `myButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonTest);`

The `int` that is expected is the id of the view that has been created which is referenced in `R.id`.

Comment: Note: you will need to also `import com.<yourstuff>.<yourapp>.R;` and NOT `Android.R`

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a function that will handle your onClick: in your case something like:

```
public void TestSoap_OnClick(View view){
        doSomething();
    }
```

Then when your button is pressed it will automatically call this function since you have:

```
android:onClick="TestSoap_OnClick"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the line android:onClick="TestSoap_OnClick" from your xml

and also replace myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
with myButton.setOnClickListener(onClick)

Comment: Thanks. But still does not help "finding" the right button. On that Line "myButton" is just an empty Button object, not the button from that View. (findViewById() does not work the way I wrote it))